# How can I display a paragraph over image?

Tags: html

I have this code:

```
    <ul class="lista_sus">                       
     <li><img src="image/1.png" alt="Smiley face" height="250" width="250"></li>
     <li><img src="image/2.png" alt="Smiley face" height="250" width="250"></li>
     <li><img src="image/3.png" alt="Smiley face" height="250" width="250"></li>
   </ul>
```

I want to display a paragraph over image.

How can i solve this problem?

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use image as a background.

Comment: which paragraph you want to show?? Need more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1: Background Image

You could use a background image for this, setting the background image in your css instead:

```css
div{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  }
```

```html
<div>This is some text</div>
```

---

## Solution 2: Absolute positioning

Or, you could use absolute positioning, placing the paragraph 'absolutely' over the image element:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
li p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista_sus">

  <li>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" alt="Smiley face" height="250" width="250">
    <p>This is a load of text</p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position : relative;
  display : inline-block;
  background : red;
  width : 200px;
}

.image {
  position : absolute; 
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
  width : 200px;
}

.textOverImage {
  position : absolute;  
  width : 100%
  color : white;
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQ4H3lSqu-QV2NrIYISCtd9WUPQf0B7zxBsjJzojdUJwMVGNNIjv4qZwo" class="image" />
  <p class="textOverImage">
    Some texts over the image
    </p>
  </div>
```

I used a `<div>` (which could also be a `<li>`, to contain the image and the paragraph.

- Container get `position : relative` CSS proprety, and should specify a width to works properly
- Contained (image, paragraph) get `position : absolute`

I let you move the paragraph wherever you want.